# Known Issues installing Visual Studio 6 with VS 2005 and 2008 already installed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

Has anyone encountered any errors when installing Visual Studio 6 on a machine which already has 2005 and 2008 installed?

Comment: Is it possible to install on a virtual pc, that would probably be the easiest solution? I dont think vs 6.0 works very well on vista/7

Comment: It may be possible to go the VM route.  The current machine in question is running XP.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Visual Studio 6 on my machine which already had VS2008 and haven't seen any problems yet related to incompatibilities between the products. What specific issue/errors are you seeing?

Comment: None, I wanted to ask before I installed.